# How to iterate throught javascript properties but skipping the function within it?

Tags: javascript

I have an object which contains a properties and a methods. I want to iterate throught it and make every single properties within it become null and leave the function as is. The object looks like this:

```
let Obj = {
   prop1: /* somevalue */
   prop2: /* somevalue */
   /* another properties goes here */
   func1: () => {
      /* do something */
   }
   /* another functions goes here */
}
```

could I do it with:

```
Object.keys(filter).forEach((key, index) => {
   /* assign null to properties */
});
```

Are functions within object getting affected?

Comment: Why do you have an object that contains both methods and unknown properties?

Answer (score 1):

You might iterate over the `entries` and check the `typeof` each value - if it's not `function`, assign `null` to the property:

```js
let Obj = {
   prop1: 'prop1',
   prop2: 'prop2',
   func1: () => {
      /* do something */
   }
}
Object.entries(Obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
  if (typeof val !== 'function') {
    Obj[key] = null;
  }
});
console.log(Obj);
```

Comment: yes mate, i just playing around and checked it. It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to loop through the keys and set the *non-function* properties to `null`

```js
let filter = {
  prop1: "1",
  prop2: "2",
  func1: () => { }
}

for (let key in filter) {
  if (typeof filter[key] !== "function")
    filter[key] = null
}

console.log(filter)
```

Or, you could get the `Object.keys` of the object created by `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filter))`

[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) creates a JSON string without `function` properties. Then use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it back to an object

```js
let filter = {prop1:"1",prop2:"2",func1:()=>{}}

Object.keys(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filter))).forEach((key, index) => {
  console.log(key)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test with `typeof` to see if it's a function - if it is, then don't do anything. If it's not, then assign it `null`:

```js
let Obj = {
   prop1: 'prop1',
   prop2: 'prop2',
   func1: () => {}
}
Object.keys(Obj).forEach(key => {
    Obj[key] = typeof Obj[key] == "function" ? Obj[key] : null;
});
console.log(Obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(e=>typeof e!=='function')
```

In filter remove the values having type function.

```js
let Obj = {
  prop1: 'a',
  /* somevalue */
  prop2: 'b',
  /* somevalue */
  /* another properties goes here */
  func1: () => {
    /* do something */
    return 'ab'
  }
  /* another functions goes here */
}

Object.keys(Obj).filter(e => typeof Obj[e] !== 'function').forEach(x => Obj[x] = null)
console.log(Obj)
```